# Datepicker ui.bootstrap on angularjs 1.3.11

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

this is my base app with angulajs 1.3.11 & ui.bootstrap. My Datepicker won't work. The date calendar don't show. Why? Thank's a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.11" data-semver="1.3.11" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js@*" data-semver="0.12.0" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>DATE TEST</h1>
    <div class="col-md-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="mydata" id="mydata" name="mydata" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And my Js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

This is my base code on http://plnkr.co/edit/dmM3NiWPF30wXM4PiiPc?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll need to do below changes.

1. Bootstrap requires jQuery
2. Add `is-open` attribute to datepicker and toggle the flag when required.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="mydata" id="mydata" 
name="mydata" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" is-open="opened" ng-click="opened = !opened"/>
```

Here is the [**Updated plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KSdPvGiSle0HHa75dGFu?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap do not require JQuery. 
OP was missing the controller and *is-open* variable. [Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/apa5hQ9lsFPJ6gfgiSTc?p=preview).

In HTML:

```
is-open="opened"
```

and in JS:

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.opened = true;
};
```